# Is using copy better than retain in all the Mutable Classes of iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, memo

I came to know that, it is better to use copy on @property of NSString than retain due to the problems you can get if you are provided with a NSMutableString. Is the same condition holds true for NSArray , NSDictionary, NSMutableData ?

Comment: What problems are you referring to?

Comment: I refer to the problem that when some one gives you a mutableString and you retain it, if the one gave you object changes it, your object would also be affected.

Answer (score 0):

By problems when retaining I'm assuming you mean that the data may unexpectedly change.

I would consider using copy if the above is unexpected for the circumstances that you are using the string or collection. So you can maintain a known copy of the string, collection or other object that is not going to change without you knowing about it.

However, there may be other reasons to use retain rather than copy on a non-mutable collection or string. You may accept that the contents may change, however use NSArray in the property to show that the object using the container will not modify it itself.

I would think the NSString properties probably want to use copy more so than not. Collections may be different, look at your requirements and see what fits best in your situation.